# Function pointer cast on function with inherited C structure

Tags: c, language-lawyer

I'm looking for answer if presented in a example function cast and call is valid in C(if not any example how to get similiar behavior would be nice).

Example:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdint.h>

typedef struct {
    uint32_t a;
} parent_t;

typedef struct {
    parent_t parent;
    uint32_t b;
} child_t;


typedef void (*funct_ptr_t)(parent_t* pParent, uint32_t x);

void test_function(child_t* pChild, uint32_t x);

int main()
{ 
    funct_ptr_t func = (funct_ptr_t)test_function;
    funct(NULL, 0U);

    return 0;
}

void test_function(child_t* pChild, uint32_t x) {
    // do something
}
```

@EDIT
As above turned to be invalid, i would like to also ask about second approach

```
typedef void (*funct_ptr_t)(void* pChild, uint32_t x);

void test_function(child_t* pChild, uint32_t x);

int main()
{ 
    funct_ptr_t func = (funct_ptr_t)test_function;
    child_t child;
    func(&child, 0U);

    return 0;
}

void test_function(child_t* pChild, uint32_t x) {
    // do something
}
```

Comment: That seems dangerous at least - the function expects a pointer to a `child_t` object, but may receive a pointer to "only" a `parent_t`. If the function then tries to access the `b` member you'll definitely invoke *undefined behavior*

Comment: The opposite would be safe, though, since the function won't try to access past the `parent` prefix.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is not valid.

A function can only be called though a compatible function pointer type.  For two function pointer types to be compatible, the corresponding arguments must have compatible types and the return types must be compatible.

`test_function` has type `void (*)(child_t*, uint32_t )` but is being called through a function pointer with type `void (*)(parent_t*, uint32_t )`.  This means the function is being called through an incompatible type and doing so triggers [undefined behavior](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Undefined_behavior).

If you're trying to accept a pointer to different types for the first parameter, the simplest way to handle this is to change the type of the first parameter for both the function and function pointer to `void *`, then perform the necessary conversion inside of the function.

Another option is to change the type of the first parameter to `test_function` to `parent_t *` and perform a cast inside the function.  This will work because a pointer to a struct can be converted to a pointer to its first member, so you could do this:

```
void test_function(parent_t* pChild, uint32_t x);

int main()
{ 
    funct_ptr_t func = (funct_ptr_t)test_function;
    child_t c;
    funct((parent_t *)&c, 0U);

    return 0;
}

void test_function(parent_t* p, uint32_t x) {
    child_t *p_Child = (p_Child *)p;
    // do something
}
```

Comment: C 2018 6.2.5 28 says all pointers to structure types shall have the same representation and alignment requirements, and note 49 says this is meant to imply interchangeability as arguments to functions. “Interchangeability” is not specified formally in the C standard, but it appears this interchangeability is intended to override issues of compatibility and was simply never elucidated in the standard.